# Exception при подключении к удаленной БД Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, tls, keystore

При попытке подключиться к удаленной базе Oracle через SSL/TLS, выводится Exception:

```
"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe"...
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Ошибка ввода/вывода: IO Error PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:874)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
                at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:406)
                at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:291)
                at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:206)
                at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:184)
                at pkapora_tls.App.main(App.java:32)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: IO Error PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:870)
                ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: IO Error PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.wrap(SSLSocketChannel.java:547)
                at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.wrapHandshakeMessage(SSLSocketChannel.java:460)
                at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.doSSLHandshake(SSLSocketChannel.java:442)
                at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.write(SSLSocketChannel.java:128)
                at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:350)
                at oracle.net.ns.NIOConnectPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOConnectPacket.java:247)
                at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:117)
                at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:340)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588)
                ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:645)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:464)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
                at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
                at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.runTasks(SSLSocketChannel.java:602)
                at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.doSSLHandshake(SSLSocketChannel.java:434)
                ... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
                at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
                at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
                at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:623)
                ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
                at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
                at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
                at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
                ... 31 more
```

В аргументах в конфигурации указала:

```
-Doracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match="true" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Users/user/client/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="**********" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType="JKS" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:/Users/user/client/keystore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="**********" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType="JKS"
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем проблема? Спасибо заранее за помощь

**p.s. Вот содержимое keystore.jks и truststore.jks**

```
C:\Users\user\client>keytool -list -keystore C:/Users/user/client/keystore.jks
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

servertest, 23 февр. 2021 г., trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 35:00:BD:30:D0:B8:69:A4:12:F0:DB:C9:60:CE:AE:F7:94:ED:D5:72:3B:41:6C:CC:A6:CB:57:98:F7:2D:83:5E
testclient, 22 февр. 2021 г., trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): EC:D0:14:18:CC:33:10:FC:5D:EB:18:66:16:F7:5B:CF:63:F2:1C:EE:B3:1D:4D:F0:1E:D8:0A:ED:2F:26:FC:0B
testroot, 22 февр. 2021 г., trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 2C:24:DD:A2:C7:74:AF:69:48:42:A5:FE:51:98:20:FF:18:5F:8E:7D:B1:1F:61:0C:29:3D:44:83:82:3F:88:2C

C:\Users\user\client>keytool -list -keystore C:/Users/user/client/truststore.jks
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

servertest, 23 февр. 2021 г., trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 35:00:BD:30:D0:B8:69:A4:12:F0:DB:C9:60:CE:AE:F7:94:ED:D5:72:3B:41:6C:CC:A6:CB:57:98:F7:2D:83:5E
testclient, 23 февр. 2021 г., trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): EC:D0:14:18:CC:33:10:FC:5D:EB:18:66:16:F7:5B:CF:63:F2:1C:EE:B3:1D:4D:F0:1E:D8:0A:ED:2F:26:FC:0B
testroot, 22 февр. 2021 г., trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 2C:24:DD:A2:C7:74:AF:69:48:42:A5:FE:51:98:20:FF:18:5F:8E:7D:B1:1F:61:0C:29:3D:44:83:82:3F:88:2C
```

**p.s.2  Добавила в класс блок статической инициализации, в котором устанавливаются необходимые значения**

```
static {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", " C:\\Users\\user\\cacerts_client\\keystore.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "**********");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", " C:\\Users\\user\\cacerts_client\\keystore.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "**********");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreStoreType", "JKS");
}
```

Появилось новое исключение:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Ошибка ввода/вывода: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:874)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
                at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:406)
                at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:291)
                at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:206)
                at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:184)
                at pkapora_tls.App.main(App.java:49)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:870)
                ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
                at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:174)
                at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:555)
                at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readNIOPacket(NIOPacket.java:403)
                at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:127)
                at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:340)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1596)
                at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588)
                ... 8 more
```

Comment: Видимо, у Вас в truststore нет сертификата Вашего сервера. Добавьте его в trustsore и все должно заработать

Comment: @Sergi Посмотрела список сертификатов в keyStore.jks - в нем были доверенный (root) и подписанный клиентский, добавила к ним серверный. В  trustStore был только доверенный (root) , добавила к нему клиентский и серверный. Попыталась запустить проект, ошибка таже. Списки сертификатов обоих хранилищ указала в своем вопросе, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Так сложно сказать, попробуйте включить дебаг TLS: `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Comment: @Sergi т.е. нужно в аргументы конфигурации вставить -Djavax.net.debug=all? Я не сильна в java, только учусь). Я добавила эту строку к остальным аргументам, ничего не изменилось, выводится текст прежней ошибки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда поместить -Djavax.net.debug=all

Comment: @Sergi А может быть причина ошибки в том, что все сертификаты, содержащиеся в хранилищах имеют формат .txt, а не .cert, например?

Comment: @Sergi также добавила в класс блок статической инициализации, в котором устанавливаются необходимые значения, появилось новое исключение (добавила в свой вопрос)